# ruby rename file with multiple string format

Tags: ruby

I have files like below on one folder.

```
helloworld
homework
server.name
server1.location.name
```

And there are many like above. I want to move some set of files with the match of first string before "."

All file names are distint. In bash we can do it by simply using * . But in ruby its not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". We'd like to see your attempt at solving this along with a question that asks about a specific problem with your code. Without that it looks like you want us to write the code for you.

Comment: I didnt request to write code. I written it already but it was giving some error when it find with names has special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through files with [Dir#glob](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob)
From the description : "Note that this pattern is not a regexp, it’s closer to a shell glob"

```
Dir.glob(pattern) each do |f|
#do something with f
end
```

where pattern could be "*" or "*.txt".
You'll need to give more information about your search.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't exactly get what you want to do but, as a sample, in this way you rename all the files in the current dir in the way you want I think.

```
2.3.1 :001 > Dir['*']
 => ["helloworld", "homework", "server.name", "server1.location.name"] 
2.3.1 :002 > Dir['*'].each { |filename| File.rename(filename, filename.split('.').first) }
 => ["helloworld", "homework", "server.name", "server1.location.name"] 
2.3.1 :003 > Dir['*']
 => ["helloworld", "homework", "server", "server1"]
```